# Time container to check event occurrence

Tags: java, time, calendar, jodatime

I would like to implement a small time container that holds 2 times, a start and an end,
, i wanna use it iterating it over events on multiple days in order to check if an event has occurred in that specific timeframe, i will have to work only on a minute/range, so the object would look like something lie this `
timeContainer(hour-minutes start, hour-minutes end);

the timeframe will be usually a range of few minutes, like 13:00pm to 13:10pm
The issue i'm having is with the milliseconds, since they represent a static final moment, they cannot be used for iteration over multiple days, i would use it as, pseudocode:

```
select events that has happened in the timeframe specified in the constructor  regardless of the day and month,
```

the events contain a Calendar instance, and i would like to perform a match against the hours and minutes, any advice?
I'm trying to rech thsi with joda-time but so far no method found

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd want to do it with milliseconds, just use the mod (%) with the number of milliseconds in a day. If you want to go with Joda-time you'll probably get something more readable. See examples below.

```
public class Test {

    static class TimeContainer {
        private static final long second = 1000;
        private static final long minute = 60 * second;
        private static final long hour = 60 * minute;
        private static final long day = 24 * hour;

        private final long starttime;
        private final long endtime;

        public TimeContainer(long startHour, long startMinutes, long endHour, long endMinutes) {
            starttime = startHour * hour + startMinutes * minute;
            endtime = endHour * hour + endMinutes * minute + minute; 
        }

        public boolean test(long timeToTest) {
            long hoursInDay = timeToTest % day;
            return hoursInDay >= starttime && hoursInDay <= endtime;
        }
    }

    static class JodaContainer {
        private final LocalTime starttime;
        private final LocalTime endtime;

        public JodaContainer (LocalTime start, LocalTime end) {
            starttime = start;
            endtime = end;
        }

        public boolean test(long timeToTest) {
            LocalTime lt = new LocalTime(timeToTest);
            return lt.equals(starttime) || lt.equals(endtime) || (lt.isAfter(starttime) && lt.isBefore(endtime));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long[] testTimes1 = new long[5];
        long[] testTimes2 = new long[5];

        Calendar test1 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/Zulu"));
        Calendar test2 = Calendar.getInstance();

        TimeContainer timeContainer = new TimeContainer(13, 0, 13, 10);
        JodaContainer jodaContainer = new JodaContainer(new LocalTime(13,0), new LocalTime(13,10));

        test1.set(2010, 10, 5, 13, 6, 20);
        test2.set(2010, 10, 5, 13, 6, 20);
        testTimes1[0] = test1.getTimeInMillis();
        testTimes2[0] = test2.getTimeInMillis();

        test1.set(2012, 9, 6, 13, 1, 24);
        testTimes1[1] = test1.getTimeInMillis();
        test2.set(2012, 9, 6, 13, 1, 24);
        testTimes2[1] = test2.getTimeInMillis();

        test1.set(2010, 11, 22, 13, 9, 1);
        testTimes1[2] = test1.getTimeInMillis();
        test2.set(2010, 11, 22, 13, 9, 1);
        testTimes2[2] = test2.getTimeInMillis();

        test1.set(2012, 10, 5, 13, 26, 20);
        testTimes1[3] = test1.getTimeInMillis();
        test2.set(2012, 10, 5, 13, 26, 20);
        testTimes2[3] = test2.getTimeInMillis();

        test1.set(2010, 10, 5, 14, 6, 20);
        testTimes1[4] = test1.getTimeInMillis();
        test2.set(2010, 10, 5, 14, 6, 20);
        testTimes2[4] = test2.getTimeInMillis();

        for (long t : testTimes1) {
            System.out.println(t + "=" + timeContainer.test(t));
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (long t : testTimes2) {
            System.out.println(t + "=" + jodaContainer.test(t));
        }

    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you really want to use Joda Time's [`LocalTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) class:

```
timeContainer(LocalTime startTime, LocalTime endTime)
```

Then in your code you just need to extract the `LocalTime` for each event given their full `DateTime`, and check whether it's after or equal to `startTime` and before `endTime`.

Answer (score 0):

You can call Date.before() or Date.after() to check whether the time is in range.

```
boolean isTimeInRange(Calendar startTime, Calendar endTime, Date date ){

            if (date.before(endTime.getTime())
                    && date.after(startTime.getTime())) {

                // time in range
                return true;

            } else {

                return false;

            }

}
```

Comment: thx, but then if i iterate over multiple days, i should recursively create new Calendars and set their time fields to the specified hour and pass them to the method, if i iterate over 200 days, it would get very very heavy